# How can i justify content between with icons using ng-bootstrap in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, material-design

***I have four icons next to each other but i want them to be separate by the same space size , i use the class `justify-content-between` but didnt work, how can i do that***

***Im doing a PWA for phones***

- Below i will let the code and also picture of how i want it and what i have until now,im using bootstrap and angular material

***Code that has the icons***

```html
<div class="main flex down fixed-bottom" >
<mat-toolbar class="colour">
    <mat-toolbar-row>

    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class=" icons "> 
            <button mat-icon-button class="icons col-xs-3" >
                <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button class="icons col-xs-3" >
                <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button  class="icons col-xs-3">
                <mat-icon>add_comment</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button class="icons col-xs-3" >
                <mat-icon>title</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

***This is how it looks like***

[image]

***This is how i want them to be***
[image]

Comment: Remove Icons Div to make 4 of buttons direct child of  row div

Comment: Still seeing the same @ArjunPandi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is how i solve it***

```html
<div class="main flex down fixed-bottom" >
    <mat-toolbar class="colour">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <div class="container icons">
                <div class=" row justify-content-between">
                    <button mat-icon-button class=" col-xs-3">
                        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button class=" col-xs-3">
                        <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button class=" col-xs-3">
                        <mat-icon>add_comment</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button class=" col-xs-3">
                        <mat-icon>title</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Your Div Structure like this.

```
<div class="main flex down fixed-bottom" >
<mat-toolbar class="colour">
    <mat-toolbar-row>

        <div class=" icons row justify-content-between"> 
            <button mat-icon-button class="icons col-xs-3" >
                <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button class="icons col-xs-3" >
                <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button  class="icons col-xs-3">
                <mat-icon>add_comment</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button class="icons col-xs-3" >
                <mat-icon>title</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>

    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: add class w-100 to near 'icons' class, it should work.